# What do they mean by Robust Cross-Validation?

Tags: cross-validation, robust, kaggle

I was reading a Kaggler Interview article and they kept specifying the importance of a stable and good cross-validation in order to win their competitions. What do they mean by that? I usually just use `cross_val_score`, and that's enough for me.

Comment: Context is everything in these situations.  Can you post a link to the article and provide a page number of paragraph if necessary?

Comment: @StatsStudent http://blog.kaggle.com/2018/05/07/profiling-top-kagglers-bestfitting-currently-1-in-the-world/

Comment: Let's put it this way: Do we find that `cross_val_score` gives us good estimates about the performance of our learner in terms of Kaggle leader-board? If, yes, then it is "good". If, no, then it is "bad". (For those who are unaware of how Kaggle works, the leaderboard ranking is usually based on unseen data.)